# JacocoTestReport doesn't cover PowerMock

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, powermockito

I am using JacocoTestReport for code coverage and it doesn't cover Power mock code coverage.
I know Jacoco and Powermockito don't go well together but wondering if there is a workaround in gradle.
I am using the below jacoco in gradle

```
dependencies {
    jacocoTestReport 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.2.201409121644'
}
```

Comment: Theres an offline work around in maven, there may be a similar work around in gradle(though I'm not familiar with gradle).

Comment: I have similar issue with gradle. Has anyone successfully tried offline instrumentation in gradle?